# How can I list the columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Normally, if I want to list columns and types in a table called `foo` in the current database, I would use the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'foo';
```

However, I want to list the columns in the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, and the following statement returns zero results.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS';
```

**What is the correct way to list the columns in the table above, in `psql`?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tablename and schema name are stored in two columns:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'columns'
  and table_schema = 'information_schema';
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html